# What is the Mutex and semaphore In c#? where we need to implement?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex, semaphore

What is the Mutex and semaphore in C#? Where we need to implement?

How can we work with them in multithreading?

Comment: that's way too big a topic to answer IMHO..do you have any specific issues?

Comment: Naveen please suggest me some decomposed question so that i can dig into it..

Answer (score 37):

You should start at MSDN.

- [System.Threading.Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx): A synchronization primitive that can also be used for interprocess synchronization.
- [System.Threading.Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx): Limits the number of threads that can access a resource or pool of resources concurrently.

Generally you only use a Mutex across processes, e.g. if you have a resource that multiple applications must share, or if you want to build a single-instanced app (i.e. only allow 1 copy to be running at one time).

A semaphore allows you to limit access to a specific number of simultaneous threads, so that you could have, for example, a maximum of two threads executing a specific code path at a time.

Comment: +1 for MSDN.  It's the RTFM-goto for everything in the Windows API space.

Comment: Semaphores can also be used to synchronize across processes."Named system semaphores are visible throughout the operating system, and can be used to synchronize the activities of processes": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8):

I'd start by reading this: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Synchronization_Essentials
 and then bolster it with the MSDN links bobbymcr posted.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to check out the lock statement. It can handle the vast majority of thread synchonization tasks in C#

```
class Test {
    private static object Lock = new object();

    public function Synchronized()
    {
        lock(Lock)
        {
            // Only one thread at a time is able to enter this section
        }
    }
}
```

The lock statement is implemented by calling Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit. It is equivalent to the following code:

```
Monitor.Enter(Lock);    
try
{
    // Only one thread at a time is able to enter this section
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(Lock);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, and potentially useful, but not really an answer to the posed question. Thought about a -1, but leaving it at this comment. ;-)

Comment: Well the implementation is changed in C# 5.0 :)