# How to execute a piece of code exactly once with multithreading in mind?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I have a function which does "migration" from an old format to a new format. I need this to occur in the constructor of my object, but not the static constructor because an argument is needed. How can I have a piece of code only execute exactly one time?

For some context:

```
class Foo
{
  public Foo(string bar)
  {
    ShouldOnlyExecuteOnce(bar);
  }
}
```

and then usage could be (with each line a different thread)

```
var f = new Foo("bar");
var fb = new Foo("meh");
etc
```

How can I properly guard the "`ShouldOnlyExecuteOnce`" method?

Because this is a sort of "migration" type function, I want for the first object created to "win" and get to migrate the old data into this new object. Later objects that get constructed should not attempt to execute this function, even if their arguments are different

Comment: Well what do you want to happen the second time the constructor is called, with a potentially different argument? It's hard to answer this in the abstract.

Comment: @JonSkeet edited to be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use double check locking.

```
class Foo
{
    private static bool ShouldOnlyExecuteOnceExecuted = false;
    private static readonly object Locker = new object();

    public Foo(string bar)
    {
        SetShouldOnlyExecuteOnce(bar);
    }

    private void SetShouldOnlyExecuteOnce(string bar)
    {
        if(!ShouldOnlyExecuteOnceExecuted)
        {
            lock(Locker)
            {
                if(!ShouldOnlyExecuteOnceExecuted)
                {
                    ShouldOnlyExecuteOnce(bar);
                    ShouldOnlyExecuteOnceExecuted = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't this cause a bottle neck around where threads are waiting for the lock, only to find that it already executed?

Comment: @Earlz Initially, but once `ShouldOnlyExecuteOnceExecuted` is set then there won't be any locking.

Comment: [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) *"The pattern, when implemented in some language/hardware combinations, can be unsafe. At times, it can be considered an anti-pattern."*

Answer (score 1):

I would generally recommend against implementing subtle mechanisms such as double-checked locking, especially when you already have them implemented in the BCL. In this case:

```
public class SafeInitializater
{
    private bool _initialized;
    private object _dummy;
    private object _syncLock;

    public void InitializeOnce(Action initializer)
    {
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _dummy, ref _initialized, ref _syncLock, 
            () => {
                initializer();
                return null;
            });
    }
}
```

Usage sample:

```
var initializer = new SafeInitializater(); //or you could make this static somewhere

var t1 = Task.Run(() => 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Task {Task.CurrentId} entering the race");
    initializer.InitializeOnce(() => Console.WriteLine($"Task {Task.CurrentId} won!"));
});
var t2 = Task.Run(() => 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Task {Task.CurrentId} entering the race");
    initializer.InitializeOnce(() => Console.WriteLine($"Task {Task.CurrentId} won!"));
});

await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
```

Answer (score 0):

A Singleton pattern should work.

Parrotting Jon Skeet:  http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx

```
 public sealed class Singleton
 {
     private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
     // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
     static Singleton()
     {
     }

    private Singleton()
     {
     }

    public static Singleton Instance
     {
         get
         {
             return instance;
         }
     }
 }
```

Singleton's are constructed one time.  Although, the part about passing in a new string value could present an issue.  Is this value ignored on all consecutive calls?

Comment: Once the get accessor has fired it's thread safe. --> This is NOT thread safe.

Comment: see http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx for proper thread safe singleton implementation

Answer (score 0):

You need a mutex. This is exactly the kind of usecase mutexes are designed for.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/mutex

Answer (score 0):

you should read about `monitors`, `semaphors` and the `sigelton design-pattern`

[What is the Mutex and semaphore In c#? where we need to implement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553012/what-is-the-mutex-and-semaphore-in-c-where-we-need-to-implement)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/threading-with-semaphore-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea, but I'd guess/try:

1 - A static class acting as a wrapper and calls your method in the static constructor

2 - Some IoC container?

3 - Singleton?

4 - Lock?

5 - All of above?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with P.Brian that this seems like a singleton pattern. You can see a very good article on it here http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx which breaks it down nicely. Generally the best solution is #4;

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static Singleton()
    {
    }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @UdoKlein yup, it is. Read the article to find out why.

Comment: @UdoKlein This one actually is. Explicit declaring a static constructor ensures that static fields are initialized as a prologue of it.